# MVC pattern : How to fix this if a model need to call its view's function?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

please please help me to fix this code based on MVC pattern.I am novice in MVC.
In my project i have to buld a tree of view & models as a parent child hierarchy.
But i stuck at a point (given in the code sample) where model need it view to call a view function with model data.As a beginner theory might difficult for me to implement.if possible then, please also suggest any more better ways.

**Pleas give some code solution.Please.**

here is a sample PHP code:

```
class model{
    $data = array();
    $model childModelArray[];  // keeps root model's child list
}
class view{
    $controller;
    function ShowChild()
    {   

        if (count($this->controller->model->childModelArray) > 0)
        {   
            echo '<div class="SubChildBox">';
            foreach ($this->controller->model->childModelArray as $nextChildModel){
                 //PROBLEM: model object  nextChildModel  need to call view object!!! ShowAsChild()  !!!
                 // Help on this please 
                 $this->ShowAsChild();
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all views doesn"t need to be a class. They are mostly html. You can solve your problem by havinng a formal parameter with default value. if the formal parameter does not exist then it is the parameter of the controller.

```
class model{
    $data = array();
    $model childModelArray[];  // keeps root model's child list
}
class view{
    $controller;
    function ShowChild($childModelArray = false)
    {   
        $childModelArray = $childModelArray === false ? $this->controller->model->childModelArray : $childModelArray;
        if ($childModelArray && count($childModelArray) > 0)
        {   
            echo '<div class="SubChildBox">';
            foreach ($childModelArray as $nextChildModel){
                 //PROBLEM: model object  nextChildModel  need to call view object!!! ShowAsChild()  !!!
                 // Help on this please 
                 $this->ShowAsChild($nextChildModel);
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```